# How to get total screen size in Python / GTK without using deprecated Gdk.Screen.get_width()?

Tags: python, screen, pygtk, gdk

I want the X/Y pixel dimensions of the entire desktop (potentially spanning multiple monitors), e.g. to determine the optimal resolution of a background image.

This Python code still works:

```
from gi import require_version
require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
print(screen.get_width(), " ", screen.get_height())
```

but prints a deprecation warning:

```
<string>:7: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Screen.get_width is deprecated
<string>:7: DeprecationWarning: Gdk.Screen.get_height is deprecated
```

The [Gdk.Screen API docs](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gdk-3.0/classes/Screen.html#Gdk.Screen.get_width) just note:

> Deprecated since version 3.22: Use per-monitor information instead

Other answers (like [How do I get monitor resolution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python) or [How to detect a computer's physical screen size in GTK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153549/how-to-detect-a-computers-physical-screen-size-in-gtk)) mention lots of other APIs and toolkits, or just give per-monitor information (like [this for PyGtk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57536282/813602)), but I think it should still be possible (also in the future) to get the dimensions of the entire desktop via PyGtk. (After all, the deprecated function also still provides this.)

Comment: What do you mean by ‘dimensions of the entire desktop’?

Comment: @user3840170: Basically the union of the resolutions of all attached monitors; if the monitors are next to each other on the desk, this would be _sum(X resolutions)_ / _max(Y resolutions)_. It could be more complex if you consider the 6+ monitor setups that e.g. stock brokers have, but somehow GTK has had this all figured out in `Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_width()` already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [the commit which removed those API calls](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/0be88cc76e756ee96839273117b464ab21a4f708), the algorithm that GDK uses to compute the screen size seems to be basically this:

```
def get_screen_size(display):
    mon_geoms = [
        display.get_monitor(i).get_geometry()
        for i in range(display.get_n_monitors())
    ]

    x0 = min(r.x            for r in mon_geoms)
    y0 = min(r.y            for r in mon_geoms)
    x1 = max(r.x + r.width  for r in mon_geoms)
    y1 = max(r.y + r.height for r in mon_geoms)

    return x1 - x0, y1 - y0

# example use
print(get_screen_size(Gdk.Display.get_default()))
```

Comment: Yes, that's giving me the same results as the deprecated GTK function, and is what I had in mind (but couldn't come up with on my own, with limited exposure to Python and GTK so far). Very nice! I hope this will serve as the authoritative answer for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have no GTK installed so unfortunately can't test, but I think something like this should work:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

display = Gdk.Display.get_default()
monitor = display.get_primary_monitor()
scale_factor = monitor.get_scale_factor()
geometry = monitor.get_geometry()
x = geometry.x * scale_factor
y = geometry.y * scale_factor

print(f'Screen Size: {x}x{y}')
```

Based on this:
https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkMonitor.html#gdk-monitor-get-scale-factor

This: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/172#issuecomment-497111004

And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63535459/7200940

Comment: That unfortunately only returns the resolution of the _primary monitor_, and ignores any other connected monitors. The old GTK had this (now deprecated) notion of a _screen_ that encompasses all active monitors; I'm searching for a corresponding abstraction in the new GTK functions (or at least a simple way to implement such abstraction myself).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest to be honest

```
from gi import require_version
require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk

screen = Gdk.Display.get_default()
w=0
h=0
for x in range(0, screen.get_n_monitors()):
     w += screen.get_monitor(x).get_geometry().width
     if ( h < screen.get_monitor(x).get_geometry().height ):
          h = screen.get_monitor(x).get_geometry().height
print (w, ' ', h)
```

Comment: the height depends on your needs actually, if you need the highest number or the lower or your screens have all the same height